# HTML form still sets PHP $_POST[] despite using Onsubmit confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

In **HTML** -

```
<form id="anID" method="post" onsubmit="confirm('Want to make this change?')" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Amount">
</form>
```

In **PHP** -

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) { Add amount to database }
```

My issue is that despite pressing "Cancel" on the `onsubmit` dialogue when it appears, the POST form is still set, and all the code inside the `PHP` `If()` statement is still submitted, I don't want this.

Is there a way to confirm the submission BEFORE `isset()` is activated?

Preferably a simple solution without the need of separate JS functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` the response from `confirm()` to stop the form from submitting (if it returns `false`. Returning `true` will allow the form to be submitted):

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Want to make this change?')"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not closed the form statement.

The most important thing - you have to set return from dialog to form.
This is the correct line:

```
<form id="anID" method="post" onsubmit="return  confirm('Want to make this change?')" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```